# Load external swf file at a specific frame in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

I need help with the conversion of the below AS2 code to AS3. 
There is a main flash file which loads a series of swfs (page1.swf, page2.swf... etc.) inside "sections" movieclip. Below code is placed on the 10th frame of "sections"

```
Stop();
LoadMovie("page1.swf", "mc");
```

The below code is on the first frame of page1.swf

```
Stop();
if (_root.counter == 1) {
    _root.counter = 2;
    this.gotoAndStop("End");
} else {
    gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

The below function is on the first frame of page2.swf.
A Back button on page2.swf when clicked will trigger this function so that when page1.swf loads on "sections" it will automatically go to the "End" frame in page1.swf.

```
function BackButton() {
    if(_root.sections != "page1.swf") {
        _root.counter=1; 
    }
}

on (release) {
    _root.screens.gotoAndPlay(10);
    BackButton();
}
```

Comment: You will get a better response if you can narrow this down to a specific question or problem you are having. Right now it just looks like you are asking for someone to rewrite your code for you.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I basically want to go to a specific frame on a loaded swf by clicking a button on another loaded swf. This is a working AS2 code but I do not know how to achieve the same in AS3.